# Barchart with Different Colors and Labels for Positive or Negative

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a simple bar chart below and I'd like to change the color of the bars if the value associated with it is positive or negative. I'd also like to change the Y labels to use different labels instead of the numbers.  For example, if the Y values are temperatures, I'd like to make the negative values blue and the positive values red. Then on the Y label, instead of having -100, I'd like it to read "Cold".

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      grid=both,
      bar width=24pt,
      ylabel near ticks,      
      yticklabel pos=right,
      symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
    ]
      \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {
        (A, -45)
        (B, -58)
        (C, -43)
        (D, 35)
        (E, 19)
        (F, 65)
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't automatic, but you can split the data over two `\addplot`s, one making blue columns, one red. You will need `bar shift=0pt`, as otherwise `pgpflots` will make room for two bars at each coordinate.

I didn't quite understand what you meant about the labels, so if you ever check back, correct me if my understanding was wrong.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      grid=both,
      bar width=24pt,
      bar shift=0pt,  %% <-- added
      ylabel near ticks,      
      yticklabel pos=right,
      symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
      ytick={-50,0,50}, %% <-- added
      yticklabels={\textcolor{blue}{Cold},0,\textcolor{red}{Warm}}, %% <-- added
    ]
      \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {
        (A, -45)
        (B, -58)
        (C, -43)
      };

      \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {
        (D, 35)
        (E, 19)
        (F, 65)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]